# What are the rules for bringing seeds into Guatemala?

Tags: guatemala

I am in the planning stages of moving to Guatemala. Since the climate in Antigua (where I plan to move to) is very similar to my native Sweden, I thought it would be nice to bring a small amount of seeds into Guatemala for growing some plans I am used to from back home. I currently live in Texas and it is way too hot here for those plants...

So am I allowed to bring a couple of envelopes with non-native berries and/or vegetables? I am for example considering these miniature strawberries:
[image: Swedish "smultron" berries]

Comment: Sweden has the same weather as Aruba?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Travel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently living in Antigua, and it's relatively easy to buy strawberry seeds here. That aside, you can pretty much bring a small amount of anything here. I brought some hard to find spices (including seeds), and have also imported some tomato seeds from the US without any hassle. If you want to bring those specific seeds, that should be fine.

Good luck with the move if it hasn't happened already!

Comment: The question is about the legal aspects (*the rules*). You are not answering that.